# alter data before update in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've looked around for answers but they say to use `update()` and it doesn't work for me

After the user updates an entity, I want to change it's data before saving it

**N.B:** the same thing is done for creating it by overriding the method `perform_create()` and it works.

Here's my code:

**The update view**

```python
class CommentUpdateAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentModelSerializer
    permission_classes  = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

**The serializer**

```python
class CommentModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model  = Comment   # the model to get fields from
        fields = [      
            'id',
            'user',
            'content',
            'timestamp',
        ]
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use `perform_update()`. Can you show what you've tried for more helpful answer?

Comment: neverwalkaloner you are right, I misused the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to neverwalkaloner,
Here is the solution:
in my `UpdateAPIView` I overrid the method `perform_update()` of Generic API Views see the docs here [GenericAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview)

And finally did this:

```python
class CommentUpdateAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentModelSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(last_update_time = datetime.now())
```